# Blu-ray drive suddenly cannot recognise any Blu-ray discs, but CDs and DVDs work fine

Tags: mount, blu-ray

I've been attempting (somewhat fruitlessly) to rip a Blu-ray disc that appears to have a bad sector on it (thanks, BBC). The problem is, after using MakeMKV to try and backup the disc, the drive is unable to read the disc at all, and after this point, the drive cannot read *any* Blu-rays at all. The drive makes a whole bunch of seeking noises, and spins up a bunch of times, but never gets anywhere, and eventually stops trying. It doesn't show anything in lsblk, no disc appears to be able to mount, nothing. CDs and DVDs continue to work fine, however.

The really weird part is that this is the second time it's happened in about a week. The first time, I put it down to a hardware failure, assuming the blue laser had died, and bought another. After patching the firmware so it works well with MakeMKV (LibreDrive and all), I ripped a Blu-ray as a test; it worked fine, so I got to work on this disc. I did the same as I already said, and the exact same thing happened.

I refuse to believe that this is a hardware issue, since it seems impossibly unlikely that two drives (albeit with the same model number and firmware) would have the exact same problem after failing to read the exact same disc. I've never heard of a drive failing because it couldn't read a disc properly.

I've tried restarting and updating my computer, to no avail. The drive refuses to take any and all Blu-ray discs, including ones that I know for a fact *work*.

The drives are the same model, the LG BH16NS55, and both have had their firmware flashed to WH16NS60 1.02MK. I'm running on Arch Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I am a silly! I had one last idea: powering off the computer, unplugging it from the wall, and leaving it for a while. After that hard reboot, it works fine now. HURRAH!

Comment: Search for "sleep bug" on Google. That might be what happened to your drive.